# Create renditions through action scripts

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting, dam

I have created some custom renditions for assets in Content Hub,so whenever i upload new asset these renditions will be created automatically, but for existing assets we need to click on refresh rendering button/link for that(to create new renditions).

Is there any way that we can write some action script which will be called from some trigger on asset modification and start a job and create these new renditions?

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Got an awesome blog, You can take the reference from that

https://www.contenthub.dev/2022/10/content-hub-tip-27-refresh-renditions.html

**Updating my answer as above blog is not working anymore and because of that reason I already got 3 down votes**

**Update** : Attaching the code snippet::

```
var targetIds = new List<long>
{
    32637
    // use a query to get your ids
};

var jobEntity = await client.EntityFactory.CreateAsync("M.Job").ConfigureAwait(false);
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.Type", "MassEdit");        
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.State", "Created");       
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.Condition", "Pending");       
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.TargetCount", Convert.ToInt64(0));       
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.TargetsCompleted", Convert.ToInt64(0));       
var jobId = await client.Entities.SaveAsync(jobEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);       

// then the description
var descriptionEntity = await client.EntityFactory.CreateAsync("M.JobDescription").ConfigureAwait(false);  
     
string jobConfiguration = $@"{{
           ""$type"": ""Stylelabs.M.Base.MassEdit.MassEditJobDescription, Stylelabs.M.Base"",
    ""Operations"": [
        {{
            ""$type"": ""Stylelabs.M.Base.MassEdit.RefreshRenditionsOperation, Stylelabs.M.Base"",
            ""Renditions"": [{string.Join(",", renditionNames.Select(name => $"\"{name}\""))}],
            ""FailedOnly"": false,
            ""RefreshHistory"": false,
            ""RefreshSubfiles"": false
        }}
    ],
    ""FinalizeOperations"": [],
    ""Targets"": [{string.Join(",", targetIds)}]
}}";       
    

descriptionEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.Configuration", JToken.Parse(jobConfiguration));       

var jobRel = descriptionEntity.GetRelation("JobToJobDescription", RelationRole.Child);       
jobRel.SetIds(new long[] { jobId });              
var descriptionId = await client.Entities.SaveAsync(descriptionEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);              

// logger.LogInformation($"Created job description {descriptionId}");       

// And finally update the job (we can only do that after the description is created)           

var loadConfig = new EntityLoadConfiguration()        
{        
    PropertyLoadOption = new PropertyLoadOption("Job.State", "Job.TargetCount"),
    RelationLoadOption = RelationLoadOption.None,
    CultureLoadOption = CultureLoadOption.Default       
};         
jobEntity = await client.Entities.GetAsync(jobId, loadConfig).ConfigureAwait(false);       
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.State", "Pending");       
jobEntity.SetPropertyValue("Job.TargetCount", Convert.ToInt64(targetIds.Count));       

await client.Entities.SaveAsync(jobEntity).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Add content from blog here as well, because this blog may not work sometimes.

Comment: Hi Gautam, this is a link only answer. To better serve this community, can you please add a more complete answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to serve better this community -Thank!

Comment: Answer is still not clear where to add the code and how to execute it.

Comment: @JumpingRabbit , The question itself specifies that it will be written in the action script and will be called through triggers.